# Which $3$-manifolds do not admit a geometric structure?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

The geometrization conjecture (now theorem) says that each $3$ dimensional manifold   decomposes into canonical pieces which admit  geometric structures. So, in general, a $3$ dimensional manifold does not admit a geometric structure. Furthermore I suppose that almost all $3$-manifolds do not admit a geometric structure. But I'm just looking for an example of such a $3$ manifold, since all examples I know admit geometric structures. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Take two hyperbolic manifolds with toral boundary and glue them along boundary tori.

Comment: Thanks you Moishe Kohan. I understand that the resulting manifold is a manifold without boundary and with an (incompressible?) embeded torus. Then, the JSJ splitting is not trivial. But is there a simpler way to see that it does not admit a geometric structure?

Comment: I suggest doing the following exercise: There are 8 3-dimensional geometries. Exclude them one by one and record this in your question: Which geometries you managed to exclude and on which you got stuck.